# Getting error code 21 on clickatell api request

Tags: clickatell

```
{"error":{"code":21,"description":"Payload data is malformed."}}
```

I am sending the request as described in the example in clickatell but when i am sending request to whatsapp messages as channel then i am getting error code 21.

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
        "to": "923172634024",
        "channel": "whatsapp",
        "content": "Example message using default channel"
      }
    }
    
]
```

}

> I am sending request to this api endpoint
> https://platform.clickatell.com/v1/message

Answer (score 2):

Your brackets don't match up. You have an extra `}` before the final `]` that needs to be removed. Everything else seems fine! Try this fix:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
        "to": "923172634024",
        "channel": "whatsapp",
        "content": "Example message using default channel"
      }
    
    
    ]
}
```